# Hiding the beginning of a text block with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overflow

I have a div element which is deliberately too small for the text inside it. I want the overflow to be hidden, but I want the text inside the div to be the 'bottom' of the text block i.e the end of the sentence to be shown and the start of the sentence to be hidden.

It would be even better if I could get an elipsis, e.g INSTEAD of a regular elipsis cutting off the end of a sentence:

|the cat jumped over...|

I would want an elipsis at the beggining of the block i.e

|...over the high fence|

Can anybody help me?

Comment: would you try to add some css to the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

1) Place the text in a wrapper element with `position:absolute` and `bottom:0`

2) Since the text will always be larger than the width of outer div...as the question says:

> I have a div element which is deliberately too small for the text
>   inside it.

...we can set an ellipsis before the text using generated content on the outer element

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/dsv2h83L/1/)**

```css
div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 18px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
div:before {
  content: '...';
  display: inline-block;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div><span>the cat jumped over the fence</span>
</div>
```